# Multiple line Carousel Caption for Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've used the Carousel Container to create a Page Header with Text centred (horizontally & vertically), as it was the easiest way to centre text over an image - refer image.
[image]

My client wants me to add a horizontal line above & below the text, as its done in this image below, but im not sure on the best way to achieve this - given everything still needs to be centred & it has to be responsive.
[image]

Here is my HTML code (excluding Navbar, as its Bootstrap);

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/community-group.jpg" alt="" class="center-block img-responsive" style="opacity: 0.8;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="text-center full-width"><h1>Contact Us </h1></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's the current CSS for handling the Carousel & Carousel Caption and making sure they're centred:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 400%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #9e9e9e;
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">

        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="text-center full-width">
                    <hr/>
                    <h1>Contact Us </h1>
                    <hr/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Simple Way:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">

        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="text-center full-width">
                <hr/>
                <h1>Contact Us </h1>
                <hr/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works @Deepakswain, though Col-sm4 isn't a wide enough column + its not longer centred over the image.
~ I'm guessing as well col-sm-4 wouldn't be large enough, as these columns are within the container, & not the full screen width.

Comment: @BlissSol, I just suggest the solution. You can use offset or expand the column size with appropriate parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can add an other class to carousel and change this carousel caption styles, whit this you have orginal carousel caption and your carousel caption.
Just change top to 50 percent and margin-top = caption height / 2

```
.verticalCarousel .carousel-caption {
   bottom:inherit;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top:-150px;
   border-top:1px solid #fff;
   border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please offer some explanation to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure how these CSS classes are supposed to be used in the HTML @MortezaNegahi